# I can't figure out how to write this "if statement"

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I need to have only the multiple gifts outputted by the names of people that gave the gift.
example: multiple toasters by: jack and jill
heres my code: thanks for the help. My loop works but not my ending if statement. confused...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var guest = "yes"
var gift, side, yourName, kind, groomNameAccum, brideNameAccum;
var toaster, silverware, stemware, giftType;
var noGift = 0;
var groomCounter = 0;
var brideCounter = 0;
kind = parseInt(kind);
//initalizing loop
weddingGift = "yes"
//start loop
while (guest == "yes") {
    side = prompt("Which side are you on? groom or bride?", "")
    yourName = prompt("Whats your name?", "");
    kind = prompt("What kind of gift?", "");

    if (side == "groom") {
        groomCounter = groomCounter + 1;
        if (groomCounter == 1) {
            groomNameAccum = "Groom     side:     <br>" + groomCounter + ". " + yourName + ": " + kind;
        } else {
            groomNameAccum = groomNameAccum + "<br>" + groomCounter + ". " + yourName + ": " + kind;
        }
    } else
    if (side == "bride") {
        brideCounter = brideCounter + 1;
        if (brideCounter == 1) {
            brideNameAccum = "<p>Bride side: <br>" + brideCounter + ". " + yourName + ": " + kind;
        } else {
            brideNameAccum = brideNameAccum + "<br>" + brideCounter + ". " + yourName + ": " + kind;
        }
    }
    if (kind > 1) {
        giftType = toaster + silverware + stemware;
    } else {
        giftType = noGift;
    }
    guest = prompt("Are there anymore guests?", "yes");
}

document.write(groomNameAccum);
document.write(brideNameAccum);
document.write("<p>Multiples Toasters by:<br>" + giftType + yourName + "<br/>");
document.write("Multiples Silverware by:<br>" + gift + "<br/>");
document.write("Multiples Stemware by:<br>" + gift);  
// --> 
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have the `// -->` at the end? It's not like any browser that's actually being used doesn't support JavaScript...

Comment: I copied and pasted it on there I must have deleted it when I was adding the four spaces. Sorry

Comment: It appears to me that you don't have kind declared properly since it is a `text` field that you are converting to an `int`. So it is a drastic change to make this work the way I believe you want it to.  Make a jsFiddle if you want more help from me.  Thanks

Comment: @JacobGarreau -- I wasn't referring to the indenting.  I was referring to the fact that this code uses a number of very bad programming practices. Everything from `prompt` to `document.write`. The best way to solve your problem is to scrap this code and replace it with something far cleaner.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I would just scrap it but this is kinda the way my teacher taught us. This is how he likes to have it written out. trust me I know on the code I have a friend that sratches his head when I tell him how I'm learning in class...lol

Comment: @JacobGarreau - Alas, that means scrapping the teacher isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

If kind should be an integer then there should be `parseInt` before `if (kind > 1) {`

```
kind = parseInt(kind);
if (kind > 1) {
    giftType = toaster + silverware + stemware;
} else {
    giftType = noGift;
}
```

Or simply

```
kind = parseInt(prompt("What kind of gift?", ""));
```

Because `promt` returns a string or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Here in the popup for "What kind of gift?" we are entering some text for that. If you are doing parseInt(kind) but its value is text only. So in java script you are not able do any operation between two different types like (int and text). So the last if condition for `if(kind > 1)` is not executing.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dMxuU/)

Comment: if (kind == "toaster") {multiples = kind + yourName ;
          } else if(kind == "silverware") {
               multiples = kind + yourName;
              }else if (kind == "stemware") {
                     multiples = kind + yourName;
                }else {
                   multiples = 0;
}